# highlight active page option value in select element using "option selected value"

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, html-lists, selectlist

I'm using a custom wp-query on my website to display all pages from a parent page inside a list style with select, when selecting a page I'm redirected to the right page.

works fine :

here is my code :

```
<?php

            $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent'    => '22',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'orderby'=>'meta_value',
            'meta_key'=>'nom_de_loeuvre'
            );

            $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <span class="styled-select">

                <select name="" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

                <option>A - Z</option>



                <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>


                        <option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php the_field('nom_de_loeuvre'); ?>
                        , de 
                        <?php if(get_field('prenom_artiste')): ?>
                        <?php the_field('prenom_artiste'); ?>
                        <?php endif ;?>
                        <?php the_field('nom_artiste'); ?> | Galerie 
                        <?php if(get_field('prenom_galerie')): ?>
                        <?php the_field('prenom_galerie'); ?>
                        <?php endif ;?>
                        <?php the_field('nom_galerie'); ?>

                        </option>



                <?php endwhile; ?>


                </select>

            </span>

            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

no I'm trying to hightlight the active page of my list, using "option selected value".
when on a page, I want the select list to display the current page in the liste.
Can anybody help me with this ?

I can't find a solution or a way to do it on the web...
I'm not sure if it's possible, but I guess if it is, It must be something to add in my Wp-query or maybe in jquery ?

thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: can you give link to your site ?

Comment: site is on localhost for the moment... I don't think you need the link non ?

Comment: You mean you want only the current page to be selected each time. ?

Comment: no, I mean when on a page, I want the list style to be on the position of the current page. the same function as option selected value. I want the current page option in my list to have the option selected value class, do you understand ?

Comment: Yes I got It. You mean `selected="selected"` , is that right. ?

Comment: no I mean <option selected value=(current page)...
i need this to be dynamic depending on which page is displayed